# Why is this loop infinite?

Tags: c++, vector, indexing, size-t

I have some code for drawing polygons edges that is supposed to draw, for example, in a triangle with vertices 0, 1, and 2, the edges (0, 1), (1, 2), and (2, 0). I thought I could accomplish this like so:

```
for(size_t j = 0, k = 1; j <= vertices.size()-1; j++, k++){
 if(j == vertices.size()-1){k = 0;} //For j to k final edge
...
//draw edges, etc. 
...
}
```

...But this makes the k value explode into an infinite loop. I have looked this over and suspect that the problem could be in my indexing here, but if everything depends on j, I would think that maybe vertices.size() is messed up. Am I missing something in this code, or should I look more closely at the actual vertices vector?

Comment: I hate it when my values explode into infinite loops...

Comment: Your loop conditional is on j, not k. So k shouldn't be "exploding" your loop.

Comment: Have you debugged it? tested the value of vertices.size()?

Comment: Well, it seems that either `j` or `vertices` is modified within the loop, in this `//etc` part. Could you show it?

Comment: I set the program to give an error and flat-out exit if vertices.size() exceeds 900. It doesn't exit there.

Comment: Somehow I have a feeling that there's rogue `if (j = 0)` somewhere in this loop... By the way, why do you have to calculate `vertices.size()` each time and not just store it somewhere? Also, what's so wrong with `j < vertsize` that you've replaced it with `j <= vertsize - 1`?

Comment: Your if-statement's body will never be entered, it uses a condition that is already caught by the for-condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not make sure that `vertices` has at least one entry the subtraction `vertices.size()-1` could lead to underflow (i.e. a very large value from the subtraction `size_t(0)-1`) and your loop could run much longer than you want.

A more idiomatic solution would be to loop

```
for (size_t j = 0, k = 1; j < vertices.size(); j++, k++) {
 if ( j == vertices.size()-1) { //works, vertices has at least one entry
   k = 0;
 }
...
//draw edges, etc. 
...
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but how come this is accepted - when @kbok answer is, well, about the same reason, and obviously a superior one?

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to count over k :

```
size_t const count = vertrices.size()
for(size_t j = 0; j < count; j++) {
  size_t k = (j + 1) % count;
  // draw
}
```

This way `k` is `j+1` except when j is the max, in that case it's 0.

Comment: and forever be damned whoever designed laptop keyboards

Comment: +1 for practical advice, -1 for not answering the question; 0 as result from me. )

Comment: @raina77ow: note the question *is* answered, just not in teaspoon/SO mode. actually i prefer this kind of answer, showing how to do it right. readers **should** have to think, because if they don't, then they will never be able to produce correct code for any non-trivial thing'

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf So now you actually know why the loop is infinite? Tell me then, I missed it somehow. )

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf how the hell does this answer why the loop is infinite? (I agree it's sound advice)

Comment: @raina77ow: compare the loop in this answer, to the OP's loop.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Well, if it turns out `vertrices.size()` was indeed 0, I'll upvote this. ) But somehow (eh...) I don't think that's the case.

Comment: @raina77ow This doesn't answer the question "why is it infinite", which I think we will never have an answer to, but it does provide an infinity-free loop, which I think is good enough for the purposes of the OP.

Comment: @kbok And that's exactly what was said in my first comment. )

Answer (score 2):

If vector "vertices" is empty, the loop will be approximately infinite. You are using unsigned integer arithmetic in the condition, so -1 will be 0xFFFFFFF or larger.

Answer (score 0):

It wont be infinite loop if everything other than you gave here is correct. So best answer is check your other parts of code carefully.